# A term that describes people who easily connect formally, but not emotionally?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, terminology

Is there a term that describes two individuals who easily connect to each other on a formal level, so, related to intellect, facts and formalities, but who hardly connect on an emotional and personal level to each other?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably referring to people who are too [cerebral](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cerebral):

> Appealing to or requiring the use of the intellect; **intellectual rather than emotional**: "His approach is cerebral, analytical, cautious" (Helen Dewar).